# Does setting document.domain via script interfere with Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a site, `www.example.com`, that displays some secure content from `forms.example.com` in iframes. To enable cross-frame navigation, pages on both sites use JavaScript to set the `document.domain` to just "example.com".

I am using Google Analytics on www.example.com, but the GA site is not showing any data. It indicates that the tracking code is found (the status icon is a green checkmark), but no data is reported.

The GA profile lists the website as "www.example.com".

Is this a supported scenario? Is my script interfering with the GA code in some way?

Comment: Has your question not been answered yet?

Answer (score 2):

A search of ga.js would suggest that the string "document.domain" (or the minified variant "E.domain") does not, in fact, appear.

It would appear as though Google Analytics uses `window.location.hostname` (encoded as `b.hostname`) to get the domain.

Comment: I know that setting the doc domain has security implications for scripts, so I was really wondering if doing so would create an error condition that would prevent the GA script from "phoning home" to the stats server. Thanks for the answer though, it might be helpful.

Comment: @Seth_Petry-Johnson - You can get all the information Google has by watching the traffic in your browser *when* the ga.js script phones home and by looking over the ga.js script itself - the Live HTTP Headers and Firebug extensions for FireFox should help with debugging... all that's left is to test :)